# Передача команд в запущенный сервис

Tags: linux, golang, администрирование

Есть go программа (несколько сайтов, чат) запускаемая как systemd сервис. Писалась под обычный запуск через терминал с управлением через команды в терминале же.

```
for {
fmt.Scanln()
/*do something*/
}
```

Вопрос следующий: как в запущенный системд сервис передавать команды, чтобы они читались программой и происходило *do something*? Либо как переписать код чтобы слышать и слушать эти команды?

Также дико интересует вопрос как обращатся с этими командами прямо к программе в терминале без набора тысяч команд?

Отдельно хочу отметить, что для *do something* есть вывод для "неправильной" (нераспозананной) команды. И по логам (journalctl) при запуске он несколько (6) раз что-то туда отправляет что это может быть и что с этим делать?

Comment: Думается, нужно было изначально разрабатывать чтение команд из сокета. Или вообще из какой-нибудь абстракции, чтобы было можно свободно переключаться между stdin и сокетом

Comment: @andreymal а примеры какие-то есть как это делать? Я просто очень долго гуглил и вообще ничего по теме не нашёл.

Comment: Вроде готовых универсальный примеров нет (или по крайней мере мне тоже не попадалось), каждый сервис делает так, как ему приспичит. Общий принцип — иметь где-нибудь сокет и клиент для подключения к нему (хотя при ручном наборе текстовых команд в качестве клиента могут сгодиться и простые netcat или telnet)

Comment: @andreymal ну то есть по сути надо открывать сокет и дописывать отдельную простенькую софтину которая будет кидать в него эти команды?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько способов, но опишу самые простые. Выбирайте по усмотрению.

1. Использование http сервера. Да, добавляем в приложение [обычный сервер](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), супер производительности тут не нужно. А дальше команды хоть curl, хоть браузером отправляются. А можно и свою супер тулу сделать. Простор для изобретательства - широчайший. Главное, что бы сервер наружу не торчал (то есть, для начала слушать хотя бы 127.0.0.1) и прикрутить примитивную авторизацию.
2. На файликах. Да, банально, да странно, но это работает. Просто время от времени (или используя [inotify](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify) сервер следит за своими файлами. Если файл поменялся - можно что то сделать. Есть много подводных камней, но кто знает, может и так.
3. Классических линукс способ - [использовать сигналы](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#Notify). В golang они завернуты в каналы, так что это может сильно упростить код. К сожалению, сигналов не так много и многие с них уже "расписаны" под конкретные задачи. Но sigusr1/sigusr2 можно повесить что то уникальное свое, а sighup сейчас часто используется как "перечитай свои конфиги".
4. Можно конечно использовать shared memory (но как по мне, это сильно пушкой по комарам) или pipe (но это те же сокеты,  нужно делать свой протокол), но выбор всегда за писателем.

Comment: все идеи — это довольно дурацкие костыли... самый нормальный вариант — сделать сокет (Unix domain или tcp) и писать в него команды, как @andreymal и сказал... разве что http-сервер допустим для некоторых применений...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну, фактически, http-сервер — разновидность использования сокета) Некоторые сервисы действительно имеют http api как один из вариантов управления собой (впрочем, мне http тоже не очень импонирует)

Comment: А где можно почитать какие есть сигналы? (Пока остановился на unix socket'ах)

Comment: можно для начала начать с [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB_(Unix)), хотя на странице руководства golang они также все есть. Лично мне кажется, что http - самый простой и надежный способ быстро сделать удобное управление. А потом, если уж сильно хочется, делать свой протокол, набивать свои шишки. С другой стороны есть ещё сотни оберток, protobuf, grpc (который сразу с сервером), zeromq...

Comment: @KoVadim такими темпами автор испугается и решит остаться на старом добром stdin)

Comment: это же линукс - тут можно так, как именно хочется или сказал соседний гуру.

Comment: Я за HTTP ))
У меня пара серверов работают с встроенным HTTP REST сервером. Очень удобно. Можно не только команды выдавать, но и запросы. Правда, возникают совершенно недетские вопросы с безопасностью. Нужно аутентифицировать пользователя, выдающего команды. У меня костыль в виде заранее известного сертификата админа, который зашит в приложение. А в общем случае надо наворачивать полноценный аутентификатор.

Comment: у меня был сервис, который спрашивал basic-auth + урл должен быть специальным (некоторые значения зависили о текущей даты). И работало как часы.

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб не переписывать сервис вместо запускаемого файла подсунь такой скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mkfifo /tmp/goservicefifo
/usr/bin/netcat --telnet --listen -p 9000 < /tmp/goservicefifo | /opt/goservice/bin/goservice > /tmp/goservicefifo
```

netcat будет слушать телнет на порту 9000 и к нему можно подключиться через putty или telnet и давать команды.

Правда она завершится при отключении от телнета. чуть позже напишу как сделать чтоб не завершался.